# Can someone give a geometric interpretation about sympy.vector.matrix_to_vector?

Tags: python, matrix, geometry, linear-algebra, sympy

SymPy [doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/api/vectorfunctions.html#matrix-to-vector) gives an explanation about this function `sympy.vector.matrix_to_vector`

> Converts a vector in matrix form to a Vector instance.
>
> It is assumed that the elements of the Matrix represent the measure numbers of the components of the vector along basis vectors of ‘system’.

and this example

```
>>> from sympy import ImmutableMatrix as Matrix
>>> m = Matrix([1, 2, 3])
>>> from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, matrix_to_vector
>>> C = CoordSys3D('C')
>>> v = matrix_to_vector(m, C)
```

It seems that C represents the coordinate axes of a 3d Euclidean space.

As per standard convention, `C.i, C.j, C.k` represent basis vectors along the ,  and  axes respectively.

It seems that `m = Matrix([1, 2, 3])` is the Matrix we're considering (the matrix to be converted to a vector). Can someone give a geometric interpretation about **converting the vector in matrix m to Vector instance**?

Is there a point (1, 2, 3) somewhere in that space? What is it for?

Answer (score 4):

There are actually a lot of implicit assumptions behind "*a point (1,2,3) in space*". When we use coordinates such as `(1,2,3)` what we really mean is a representation (a specific thing) of an abstract object (an element of a set; the set is a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) ℝ³ and an element is called a vector).

The way we represent vectors in vector spaces is that we first specify [a basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) and then use the guaranteed-to-be-real numbers which define a unique linear combination of the basis vectors that specify a given vector in the vector space.  When we colloquially say "*a point (1,2,3)*" we imply

- the linear space (vector space) is ℝ³
- the basis is the canonical Cartesian basis `i`, `j`, `k` which is an [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis).

So coming back to your question: the "vector in matrix form" `[1, 2, 3]` can only be made sense of if we have a good understanding of the vector space and the basis, especially the latter. If our basis is the Cartesian basis then this is the point `1i + 2j + 3k` which has a distance of `sqrt(14)` from the origin. If our basis was something else (and we can have infinitely many valid bases in a given vector space), say, `I = 2i - 3j`, `J = -k + i` and `K = j + 2k` then on this basis the same coordinates `(1,2,3)` (note that I used parentheses instead of square brackets to indicate the change in basis) would correspond to the point `1I + 2J + 3K = (2i-3j) + 2(-k + i) + 3(j + 2k) = 4i + 0j + 4k` which has a distance of `sqrt(32)` from the origin.

So the core of the problem is that coordinates are tied to a basis, and the "matrix form" of the vector can only contain coordinates. But using `sympy.vector` you can use abstract vectors as first-class objects, in the doc's example the matrix `[1,2,3]` gets converted to `C.i + 2*C.j + 3*C.k` which is a well-defined element of a well-defined linear space. If you use a different basis to do the conversion you will get a different (but again well-defined and abstract) element of the vector space.

And the final step (i.e. the geometric interpretation) is that elements of the vector space ℝ³ correspond to what we think of as points in 3d real space. So yes, in the example you showed from the docs this transformation from "matrix form" to vector is a bit hard to grasp, because there's only a subtle change from concrete representation to abstract. Choosing different bases for the conversion might make it more obvious that what we call `[1,2,3]` should not be taken for granted.